# how to pass values between two repeateres on the same page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I have two repeaters that looks like this :

```
Arrange By: Name | Age | Area
```

what I want to do now is to populate the second repeater from the database with the alphabet, and if the age was clicked then the second repeater gets populated from the database with some age ranges!

I already implemented my idea by placing a hyperlink in the first repeater, that passes -using it's NavigateUrl property- a url for the same page but with some querystring values!

I've been told that querystrings are used for passing values from one page to another, not the same page...and also I wanted to use some AJAX (script manager and update panel) but turns out that I have to use some server control within my repeater instead of html controls so it could be able to post back to the server

I hope you'd help me with a good implementation for passing the value from repeater1 to repeater2 and if you think that I've stated anything wrong Please Corret Me!

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT**

my.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string commandString1 = "SELECT [arrange_by_id], [arrange_by] FROM [arrange_by]";


            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(commandString1, cn))
                {
                    cn.Open();

                    using (SqlDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        ArrangeBy_rpt.DataSource = dr;
                        ArrangeBy_rpt.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
          }

    void arrange_lnkbtn_command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
         Label1.Text = (e.CommandArgument).ToString();
    }
```

my.aspx

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="ArrangeBy_rpt" runat="server">
       <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:LinkButton id="arrange_lnkbtn" OnCommand="arrange_lnkbtn_command" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("arrange_by_id") %>' runat="server">
          <%# Eval("arrange_by") %>
          </asp:LinkButton>
       </ItemTemplate>
       <SeparatorTemplate> | </SeparatorTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

Compilation Error

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.sortingcontrol_ascx' does not contain a definition for 'arrange_lnkbtn_command' and no extension method 'arrange_lnkbtn_command' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.sortingcontrol_ascx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
Line 4:  <asp:Repeater ID="ArrangeBy_rpt" runat="server">
Line 5:     <ItemTemplate>
Line 6:        <asp:LinkButton id="arrange_lnkbtn" OnCommand="arrange_lnkbtn_command" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("arrange_by_id") %>' runat="server">
Line 7:        <%# Eval("arrange_by") %>
Line 8:        </asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong *per se* with passing data to the same page using the querystring, though it shouldn't be used for sensitive data that the user might change by "hacking" the URL. However, it's not the standard way of doing things in ASP.NET WebForms, since it won't postback the values of any other controls on the page (and hence they won't retain their state without you manually having to re-populate them on every page load). But if this is not a problem for you, feel free to stick with querystring.

Howecer, *generally* you would use a server-side control like an [asp:Button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.commandargument.aspx) or an [asp:LinkButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx) and then handle their OnClick event. However, to pass data with one you can use the  [CommandName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.commandname.aspx) and [CommandArgument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.commandargument.aspx) properties of the button and then handle the [OnCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.oncommand.aspx) event.

```
 <asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton1" 
           Text="Click Me"
           CommandName="Age" 
           CommandArgument="18" 
           OnCommand="LinkButton_Command" 
           runat="server"/>
```

In code-behind:

```
  void LinkButton_Command(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e) 
  {
     var data = GetData(e.commandArgument); // implement a method that gets your data filtered by the argument passed from the button
     Repeater2.DataSource = data;
     Repeater2.DataBind();
  }
```

Comment: your answer was simple and straight, but If you read my question this linkbutton is placed inside a repeater and depending on the clicked linkbutton value, the second repeater will be populated according to this value -How to do it! this is what I kindly hope to know-

Comment: @lKashef I've updated my answer to show one way. Obviously I don't know how your data is stored, or how you retrieve it, but you basically need to get your data and filter it based on the argument passed from the button command and then bind it to your second repeater.

Comment: it's more clear, THANKS TO YOU...but I don't know how to handle the events of linkbutton when it's inside the repeater.
in the design view it won't let me double click the linkbutton..just the parent repeater!
Then I tried to hard code it, it showed this error "are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"!

Comment: yh Dan, I see but if it helps..I store my data in a database and I use ADO.NET classes (sqlconnection, sqlcommand, etc) to access them...yh I will absolotely need to (in my old implementation, i've used command.parameters, to add a parameter to the command, what do you think ?)

Comment: You will probably need to hand-code it, but the example above you show you the event signature. Just make sure the method name handling the event is the same as the value in the OnCommand property of the button. If you are still stuck then update your question with some code so we can see what you are trying.

Comment: @lKashef - Try making your `arrange_lnkbtn_command` method protected so it is accessible ie. `protected void arrange_lnkbtn_command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)`